# Estoy aprendiendo a programar y tengo un proyecto que en ambiente de desarrollo funciona correctamente, pero en producción me da un error

Tags: php

La estructura de mis carpetas están así
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el index.php estoy llamado al router
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

y asi tengo el controlador
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

El problema se da cuando subo el proyecto a un servidor solo se muestra la página de inicio y las internas me sale error 404, por favor si alguien sabe como puedo solucionar este problema me ayudaría mucho por favor

Comment: Buenas, Geovanny, el error 404 se produce cuando el servidor no encuentra el recurso requerido. Si has replicado exactamente tus carpetas en el servidor, probablemente se trate de un problema de configuración en el servidor.  Poco se puede hacer con los datos que aportas, desconocemos cómo se configura ese servidor que mencionas.

Comment: Saludos RubioRic. Pense que me hacia falta un htaccess o algo así de todos gracias por responder

Comment: Mira el código fuente en el navegador y mira las rutas con error, pueda que ahí veas cual es el problema. Si pones el link le doy una revisada...

Comment: es posible que te haga falta un htaccess si esta en tu local y no esta en tu web host ... aveces pasa y hay que crearlo manualmente y ponerle el contenido... por otro lado hay que ver que regista el apache como url que te sale el error 404